# How to get number of columns <td> or <th> in a row <tr>?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the number of columns in a given row, when I use below snippet

```
int size = element.findElement(By.xpath("/tr[" + Row + "]")).findElements(By.tagName("td")).size();
```

I get an exception stating NoSuchElementException.

Below is the HTML block

```
<table class="DynamicOrderTable" id="customerOrderHeader">
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);">
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
        <th>Order Sub-status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Temp">
        <td class="close" id="orderNumber">
            <div class="clickableText">1234</div>
        </td>
        <td class="close">1</td>
        <td class="close" id="customerName">ABC101</td>
        <td title="OrderResponse Sequence Number:14" class="close" id="orderStatus"><div class="clickableText">Complete</div></td>
        <td class="close">Closed</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to get the number of columns in a row when we have thead and tbody tags?

Answer (score 1):

Your code to get column size is correct, just change `/tr` to `.//tr` in your `xpath` as :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("customerOrderHeader"));

int size = element.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[" + Row + "]")).findElements(By.tagName("td")).size();
```

Or

```
int size = element.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).get(Row).findElements(By.tagName("td")).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, code below should help you to get no. of columns.

**Using XPath**

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="customerOrderHeader"]/tbody/tr[1]/th")).size();
```

**Using CssSelector**

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table#customerOrderHeader>tbody>tr:first-child>th")).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

use cells property with row index

```
 document.getElementById("customerOrderHeader").rows[0].cells.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code:

```
int count =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[@class='Temp']//td")).size();
System.out.println("count is "+count);//output is count is 5
```